# Conditional Breaks after 2.9 upgrade

Tags: conditionals, advanced-conditionals

I was successfully using the following block of code until I upgraded to EE 2.9.0.

```
{exp:query sql="SELECT COUNT( * ) AS itemCount FROM exp_freeform_form_entries_4 WHERE form_field_52 = 'yes'"}
        {if 15 > {itemCount}}
                  <td><label for="setup_1">Mon. Dec. 9, Setup/iron - 9am-noon: {exp:query sql="SELECT 15 - COUNT( * ) AS itemNeeded FROM exp_freeform_form_entries_4 WHERE form_field_52 = 'yes'"}{itemNeeded}{/exp:query} needed </label>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="setup_1" id="setup_1" value="Yes" /></td>
        {if:else}
            <td>Monday 9-noon is full</td>
        {/if}
    {/exp:query}
```

Now however I get the following error message when I try and load the page:

> Error
>
> You have an invalid conditional in your template. Please review your
>   conditionals for an unclosed string, invalid operators, a missing },
>   or a missing {/if}.
>
> Parser State: Unexpected end of Template “apex/volunteer-form” on line
>   2; expected ENDIF tag for opening on line 1.

I have carefully checked the page and don't see any missing {/if} or }. Any suggestions for what I am missing here?

Comment: Did you try removing the brackets from "{if 15 > {itemCount}}" to "{if 15 > itemCount}" OR to "{if 15 > '{itemCount}'}"??

Comment: Mark, I did try both of those, but without success. That is where the problem is, because if I replace {itemCount} with a number like 6, the error goes away. Is there another way to do itemCount?

Comment: And you verified that itemCount is in fact outputting? I thought there was a conditional bug reported with 2.9 but I can't find it :// did you try upgrading to 2.9.2?

Comment: Yes it does provide an output and does not through an error, unless I put it inside the if statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some experimenting and with some leading questions from Mark was lead to discover that {itemCount} needs to be inside of quotes but not inside of { }.

So the final solution is:

```
{exp:query sql="SELECT COUNT( * ) AS itemCount FROM exp_freeform_form_entries_4 WHERE form_field_52 = 'yes'"}
        {if 15 > "itemCount"}
                  <td><label for="setup_1">Mon. Dec. 9, Setup/iron - 9am-noon: {exp:query sql="SELECT 15 - COUNT( * ) AS itemNeeded FROM exp_freeform_form_entries_4 WHERE form_field_52 = 'yes'"}{itemNeeded}{/exp:query} needed </label>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="setup_1" id="setup_1" value="Yes" /></td>
        {if:else}
            <td>Monday 9-noon is full</td>
        {/if}
    {/exp:query}
```

With the conditional as:

```
{if 15 > "itemCount"}
```

Comment: Ahh haa! Happy to hear you got it sorted out.